# shift every other elements of linkedlist (in place) to end of linkedlist in java

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, singly-linked-list

The questions is as follows:
given a `linked list`, shift the alternate `indices` to back of `list`

for ex:

```
input:         :  [0] -> [1] -> [2] -> [3] -> [4] -> [5] -> [6] -> [7]
expected output:  [0] -> [2] -> [4] -> [6] -> [1] -> [3] -> [5] -> [7] /
```

As you can see from the expected output, elements at odd positions (indices) are moved to back of `linkedlist`.  I tried to implement this; I could get the odd indices removed and but they are not linking to the end of list.

my Code is here:

```
public void shift(){
    if (front==null) return;

    ListNode curr=front;
    ListNode temp=curr.next;
    while (curr.next!=null && curr.next.next!=null){
        curr.next=curr.next.next;
        curr=curr.next;
        temp.next=curr.next;
     }
     curr.next=temp;
    temp.next=null;
}


expected output: front -> [0] -> [2] -> [4] -> [6] -> [1] -> [3] -> [5] -> [7] /
my output: front -> [0] -> [2] -> [4] -> [6] -> [1] /
```

I need some assistance here

P.S: No Auxiliary storage must be used. No other containters!!!. so this is an in-place re-arrangement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form a list with the elements at odd indices and another list with the elements at even indices. Append the odd list to even list. The time complexity is O(n) and the auxiliary space complexity is O(1).

```
    public void shift() {
       if (front == null)
            return;
        ListNode oddList, even, odd;
        oddList = even = odd = front;
        oddList = front.next;
        while (even.next != null) {
            odd.next = even.next;
            odd = even.next;
            even.next = odd.next;
            if(odd.next != null) {
                even = odd.next;
                odd.next = null;
            } else {
                odd.next = null;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(oddList != null) {
            even.next = oddList;
        }
        //"front" points to the start of the new list.
   }
```

Comment: @VinodKumar: This one works!. Inside your while loop, the first line `odd.next = even.next;`, points to same node in the beginning, i.e even.next and odd.next are same..?

Comment: Yes. The odd index elements are linked using odd.next = even.next; It is like, previous odd's next is current even's next (which is current odd)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store a reference to the back of the list. Then, traverse the list, and add every other element to the end.

```
public void shift() {
    if (front == null)
        return;

    ListNode curr = front;
    ListNode temp;
    ListNode back = front;
    while (back.next != null)
        back = back.next;
    ListNode originalBack = back;

    while (curr.next != originalBack){
        temp = curr.next;
        curr.next = curr.next.next;
        temp.next = null;
        back = back.next = temp;
        curr = curr.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: that would be O(n^2)  I guess. I guess it should be possible in single traversal of list.

Comment: no, it is not. you really, really, really need a reference to the back of the list so you can put the elements on there.

Comment: it is O(n) but you are doing two traversal. my initial thought was to append the links removed to the pointer to  index-1. At the end, current will be at the end of list. so I will link current.next to the pointer at index-1 (which have others links attached)..does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

While traversing, pop every other item out, and link those together to make a second list. When you reach the end of your first list, append the second list.  I'm on my ipad so I can't code but will post once I get online.

Comment: I forgot to mention; no auxillary list should be used. I will update my question

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in this way my friend, hope this helps you

```
public void shift(){
    if (front==null) return;

    ListNode curr=front;
    ListNode temp=curr.next;
    while (curr.next!=null){
        curr.next=curr.next.next;
        curr=curr.next;

     }
     curr.next=temp;

}




after 1st pass 0->2, 
after 2nd pass 1->3,
after 3rd pass 2->4, 
after 4th pass 3->5,
after 5th pass 4->6, 
after 6th pass 5->7,

and then 7->next is null so we assign tmp to it which is pointing to 1.
```

Comment: @user1988876, My friend, I have edited my code for better explanation.

Comment: try running it and see, I tried and it gave `[0] -> [2] -> [4] -> [6] -> [1] `, which is similar to what I got above